# Is there a way to display postscript (.ps) files on iOS?

Tags: pdf-generation, postscript

I need to display .ps files in an iOS app. **Native support for .ps to .pdf conversion appears to be switched off** -- CGPSConverter,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpsconverter?language=occ

are not available on iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_ps_convert/dq_ps_convert.html

Does anyone know of another way? Is there any 3rd party library that could help me here?

*Please note that a Ghostscript/Pdftk based solution won't work due to GPL licensing terms.*

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Ghostscript is available under a commercial licence as well as GPL. In order to render a PostScript file you will need a PostScript interpreter, and there aren't very many of those. All the ones I know of are either GPL or commercial.