# Render PDF to PostScript on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf-generation, postscript

Question:  Is there a way to convert a PDF file to PostScript within an iOS application?

I have looked at the native iOS framework and Apple provides the ability to go the other way, Postscript to PDF but not PDF to PS.  I have also looked at some of the PDF SDKs that are available for iOS such as PSPDFKit but they are focused on PDF only, no PS.  In addition, I looked at using Ghostscript but the instructions here: http://www.labs.saachitech.com/2014/03/16/ghostscript-ios-static-library/ are from four years and is targeting the 32-bit iOS/old version of XCode and I need to compile for 64-bit iOS and a reasonably new version of XCode.  I ran into some really old SO posts such as this: [Is there a way to display postscript (.ps) files on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225962/is-there-a-way-to-display-postscript-ps-files-on-ios) but it really did not give any useful information.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: As far as I'm aware Ghostscript builds and runs on IOS, though I don't think we have any makefiles for it. There are build instructions here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Make.htm. I believe Poppler will produce PostScript also, you could look at that. Note that you aren't (ideally) **rendering** you are converting PDF to PostScript. However some content (transparency for example) may need to be rendered

Comment: To the question posted by meaning-matters, the iOS app needs to send the generated PDF directly to non-AirPrint capable printers. Using an older version of Ghostscript, the app can do that now.  However, we need to move the app to 64-bit and need to recompile the Ghostscript library to a 64-bit library that can be included within an iOS app.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:pdf-generation]? That is for *generating* PDF, you seem bent on *consuming* PDF and *PS generation*. Text only using only the standard PostScript fonts *should* be possible *without rendering*.